# Should hiberfile.sys be visible on a windows 8.1 machine?

Tags: windows-8.1, hibernate

I'm currently trying to fix my shutdown, sleep and hibernate issues on my laptop. One thing I am currently investigating is the hibernate resumer in my BCD. It seems to referenced hiberfile.sys in the root of C, however windows explorer cannot see it. I was wondering if this is correct?

E: I can see it using dir /a *.sys and hex editor but not in explorer. Is this normal? If i try to delete it it says cannot be found. If i try to access it is says it is currently in use.

What gives?

Comment: Check your Folder Options. [x]Hide Protected System Files is ALWAYS on by default. And hiberfil.sys is one of that protected system files. Once you untick that, there are lots of system-protected hidden files you can see. So yes it CAN be visible, but often it is hidden, unless you have a reason why you need to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make this as an answer and also to answer your edit:

Check your Folder Options. 
`[x]Hide Protected System Files` is ALWAYS on by default. And hiberfil.sys is one of that protected system files.

Once you untick that, there are lots of system-protected hidden files you can see. So yes it CAN be visible, if you have a reason why you need to find it.

In response to your edit:
    dir /a *.sys 
will return a result as /a means it will ignore whatever File Attributes (hidden in this case) that was set and return the result to you.

Not visible in explorer is normal (again will be visible after you unhide protected system files).

If you want to delete hiberfil.sys simply turn off your Hibernate function on windows. One easy way is to open command prompt (as administrator), and type

```
powercfg -h off
```

It will turn off the Hibernate function of your computer, and also automatically delete the hiberfil.sys file. If you actually DO need hibernate function (mostly for laptop, not so much for PC), you can turn it on again by changing `off` to `on` with the above command.